# trigger a radio button after ajax success call

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which shows and hides some data based on the class

```
$(document).on('change','input[type=radio][name=sp]',function() {
    if (this.value == 1)
            $(".mycklass").removeClass("hidden");
        else
            $(".mycklass").addClass("hidden");
    });
```

i am calling this in the ajax suceess

```
$('input[type=radio][name=sp]').trigger();
```

but it is not working, i placed an insert inside the above function and it shows me value first as 1 and then 0 after ajax call, what should i do to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should trigger the change event instead :

```
$('input[type=radio][name=sp]').trigger('change'); 
//Or
$('your_selector').attr('checked', true).change();
```